# How to update UI with data from different class in some other package in java swing

Tags: java, swing

I have a class with all GUI in which i have a jtextarea to show my runtime logs. In this class i have a button to call another class called test.java which performs some tasks i would like to send time to time update from test.java class to UI.java class to inform user on whats happening. I tried swingworker but it gets updated after the test.java class operation executes i also used swingutilities.invokelater but that too updates the jtextarea after test.java executes completely.
My code

UI.java(to receive data from test.java)

```
  public static void log(String msg) {
     l.setText(l.getText()+System.lineSeparator()+msg);;
   
 }
```

Test.java(to send data to UI.java)

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            p.log("unzipping  "+in);
          }
        });
```

here "in" is the file browsed by user.

I call test.java like this in UI.java

```
   bt3.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){  
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){  
            
            
            
            SwingWorker<Boolean, String> worker = new SwingWorker<Boolean, String>() {
                   @Override
                   protected Boolean doInBackground() throws Exception {
                    // Simulate doing something useful.
                       l.setText("Performing Manual Test");
                       Manualtest m=new Manualtest();
                       m.main(args);
                      
                    // Here we can return some object of whatever type
                    // we specified for the first template parameter.
                    // (in this case we're auto-boxing 'true').
                    return true;
                   }

                   // Can safely update the GUI from this method.
                   protected void done() {
                    
                    boolean status;
                    try {
                     // Retrieve the return value of doInBackground.
                     status = get();
                   //  l.setText("Completed with status: " + status);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                     // This is thrown if the thread's interrupted.
                    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                     // This is thrown if we throw an exception
                     // from doInBackground.
                    }
                   }

            
                  
                  worker.execute();
                
                }  
            });
```

my complete GUI code

```
 Production frame =new Production();
       

      
        JPanel left = new JPanel(null);
        
        
        //JPanel flow = new JPanel();
        //flow.setLayout(null);
        JLabel l2 = new JLabel("Serial Number");
        JTextField text1 = new JTextField();
        l2.setBounds(50, 120, 100, 20);
        text1.setBounds(150, 120, 150, 20);
        
        //grid 1
        left.add(l2);
        left.add(text1);

        
        
        String data[][] = {{"Image","N/A"},{"Bios","N/A"},{"QA Test","N/A"}};
        String[] header = {"Category","Status"};
        JTable table = new JTable(data,header);
        table.setBounds(50, 250, 300, 100);
        JComboBox<String> cb = new JComboBox<>();
        cb.addItem("1");
        cb.addItem("2");
        cb.addItem("3");
        TableColumn c1 = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(1);
        c1.setCellEditor(new DefaultCellEditor(cb));
        table.setRowHeight(30);
        JButton bt1 = new JButton("Deploy Image");
        bt1.setBounds(400, 250, 130, 25);
        JButton bt2 = new JButton("update Bios");
        bt2.setBounds(400, 280, 130, 25);
        JButton bt3 = new JButton("Runtest");
        bt3.setBounds(400, 312, 130, 25);
        JButton bt4 = new JButton("Generate Logs");
        bt4.setBounds(380, 400, 180, 40);
        JScrollPane sp=new JScrollPane(table); 
        sp.setBounds(50, 250, 300, 120);
        //table.setFillsViewportHeight(true); 
        sp.setViewportView(table);
        left.add(sp);
        left.add(bt1);
        left.add(bt2);
        left.add(bt3);
        left.add(bt4);
    left.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        
        
        
        
    bt3.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){  
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){  
            
            
            
            SwingWorker worker = new SwingWorker() {
                   @Override
                   protected String doInBackground() throws Exception {
                    // Simulate doing something useful.
                       l.setText("Performing Manual Test");
                       Manualtest m=new Manualtest();
                       m.main(args);
                      
                    // Here we can return some object of whatever type
                    // we specified for the first template parameter.
                    // (in this case we're auto-boxing 'true').
                    return "finished";
                   }

                   // Can safely update the GUI from this method.
                   protected void done() {
                    
                    String status;
                    try {
                     // Retrieve the return value of doInBackground.
                     status = (String) get();
                   //  l.setText("Completed with status: " + status);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                     // This is thrown if the thread's interrupted.
                    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                     // This is thrown if we throw an exception
                     // from doInBackground.
                    }
                   }

                   
                   // Can safely update the GUI from this method.
                 public void process(String chunks) {
                       
                    }
                   
                   
                  };
                  
                  worker.execute();
                
                }  
            }); 
    bt4.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){  
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){  
             Unzip u;
            try {
                u = new Unzip();
                u.main(args);
            } catch (IOException e2) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e2.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InterruptedException e2) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e2.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ArchiveException e2) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e2.printStackTrace();
            } catch (SAXException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (TikaException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (DocumentException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            
                
                }  
            }); 
        
        JPanel right = new JPanel();
        right.setLayout(new BoxLayout(right,BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

      //  JPanel debub=new JPanel();
         debub.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
      debub.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("RunTime Logs"));
     // JLabel l=new JLabel("Debug Logs");
      debub.add(l);
    right.add(debub);
    
    
    
   
    
    JSplitPane splitPane = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT, left,right);
    splitPane.setDividerLocation(650);
      splitPane.setEnabled(false);
    
      frame.add(splitPane);
      frame.setTitle("Production2");
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setResizable(false);
 }
```

So simply how to send all system.out statements time to time to UI.java to update Jtextarea to inform user.

Comment: Can you show the code where you create your GUI?

Comment: @maloomeister added GUI code

Comment: Can you add the code where you actually create it? Do you create and show your `Production` in the EDT?

Comment: i call the unzip class from production and want to update my Textarea in production